# Padding won't go away on the last a child

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a navigation menu and i'm using `:after` , `:before` , `:last-child`. The padding on my last a child I can seem to no get rid.  I've added a red background to the links so it is easy to understand. All I want is equal padding around the links

```css
.content-nav {
  height: ;
  width: ;
  background: ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10pt
}

.content-nav a {
  color: #000;
  padding: ;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: red
}

.content-nav a:after {
  content: " + ";
  padding: 0 5pt 0 5pt;
  color: rgb(246, 22, 66)
}

div.content-nav a:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="content-nav">
  <h1>Navigate the site</h1>
  <a href="company.php" title="Company - (About Us, Projects)">company</a>
  <a href="careers.php" title="Job Openings">careers</a>
  <a href="contact.php" title="Contact Us">contact</a>
  <a href="contact.php" title="Refer to Contact Page">support</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just removed the padding of the last element... i hope this is what you were looking for :)

```css
.content-nav {
  height: ;
  width: ;
  background: ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10pt
}

.content-nav a {
  color: #000;
  padding: ;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: red
}

.content-nav a:after {
  content: " + ";
  padding: 0 5pt 0 5pt;
  color: rgb(246, 22, 66)
}

div.content-nav a:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-nav">
  <h1>Navigate the site</h1>
  <a href="company.php" title="Company - (About Us, Projects)">company</a>
  <a href="careers.php" title="Job Openings">careers</a>
  <a href="contact.php" title="Contact Us">contact</a>
  <a href="contact.php" title="Refer to Contact Page">support</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the padding to 0:

```css
div.content-nav a:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  padding: 0 0 0 5pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added  `padding-right: 0;` to `div.content-nav a:last-child:after`

```css
.content-nav {
  height: ;
  width: ;
  background: ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10pt
}

.content-nav a {
  color: #000;
  padding: ;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: red
}

.content-nav a:after {
  content: " + ";
  padding: 0 5pt 0 5pt;
  color: rgb(246, 22, 66)
}

div.content-nav a:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-nav">
  <h1>Navigate the site</h1>
  <a href="company.php" title="Company - (About Us, Projects)">company</a>
  <a href="careers.php" title="Job Openings">careers</a>
  <a href="contact.php" title="Contact Us">contact</a>
  <a href="contact.php" title="Refer to Contact Page">support</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding: 0pt to your CSS.

```css
.content-nav {
  height: ;
  width: ;
  background: ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10pt
}

.content-nav a {
  color: #000;
  padding: ;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: red
}

.content-nav a:after {
  content: " + ";
  padding: 0 5pt 0 5pt;
  color: rgb(246, 22, 66)
}

div.content-nav a:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  padding: 0pt
}
```

```html
<div class="content-nav">
  <h1>Navigate the site</h1>
  <a href="company.php" title="Company - (About Us, Projects)">company</a>
  <a href="careers.php" title="Job Openings">careers</a>
  <a href="contact.php" title="Contact Us">contact</a>
  <a href="contact.php" title="Refer to Contact Page">support</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need proper selector `.content-nav a:last-child:after` 
see below code

```
.content-nav a:last-child:after {
    padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v2vd92rz/